# Two history tables for system-versioned tables shown

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temporal-tables, sql-server-2017-express

Today I noticed that one of my many databases in SQL Server has two history tables for all system-versioned tables in the database.

[image]

Both tables have similar content but NOT IDENTICAL. One history table has more records than the other. I tried to switch system versioning off and back on again.  When I switch it off, the history tables disappear (of course). But when I switch it back on, I get the same two history tables again...??
I used this to try this out:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ba SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);   
ALTER TABLE ba SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.ba_his , DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON ));   
GO
```

The weird thing is it happened only to one of the databases as far as I can tell, but for all system versioned tables in that database.

How can I correct this situation? I only want one history table

==========

Additional info:
The second history table appears to be of another database. If I query the history table using the SSMS context menu, it shows different databases:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS ******/ 
SELECT TOP (10000) [baID] ,[baTypeID] , etc... 
FROM [esx100-1888888P].[dbo].[ba_his] 

SELECT TOP (10000) [baID] ,[baTypeID] , etc... 
FROM [esx100-1246890P].[dbo].[ba_his]
```

Somehow the history table of another database is showing underneath the wrong database! How on earth did this happen? I created database esx100-1888888P a few weeks ago.

I checked database esx100-1888888P and yes, it also shows two history tables. The same tables as the other database. Somehow the table-database link data in SQL-server is messed up. Is this something that went wrong in the master database? –
emphyrio
3 mins ago

Comment: It is just a bug in your SSMS version. Get the last SSMS version and that will be correct.

Comment: When you turn off system versioning the history table isn't dropped, it becomes a "normal" table. What do you see when you query `sys.tables where name='ba_his'` or use the `ba` table with `for system_time` criteria?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to have two different tables in the same schema both called `ba_his`. When you query them what do the queries look like? There must be a distinction in the table names if you are seeing different results

Comment: If I query sys.tables it show only one table: 
SELECT * FROM sys.tables where name='ba_his'
The weird thing is that if I query the history table myself, I get 75 records.  If I query both tables shown in SSMS by using the context menu of SSMS, one table shows 67 records, the other shows 75 records. But the sql statement generated by SSMS is exactly the same... !

Comment: Can you diff the SQL statements? Maybe one has a zero width space in the name or something

Comment: I installed the last version of SSMS, version 18.10. But the double history tables are still there... just for that one database.

Comment: Ok, now it becomes really weird: the sql statements are NOT the same:

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
  SELECT TOP (10000) [baID]
      ,[baTypeID]
   , etc...
  FROM [esx100-1888888P].[dbo].[ba_his]

  SELECT TOP (10000) [baID]
      ,[baTypeID]
   , etc...  
  FROM [esx100-1246890P].[dbo].[ba_his]

Somehow the history table of another database is showing underneath the wrong database! How on earth did this happen? I created database esx100-1888888P a few weeks ago. What is going one here?

Comment: Add additional info by editing your question, comments don't always display properly or get read by everyone.

Comment: I checked database esx100-1888888P and yes, it also shows two history tables. The same tables as the other database. Somehow the table-database link data in SQL-server is messed up. Is this something that went wrong in the master database?

Comment: I would have thought definitely an SSMS bug showing you the wrong info.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted database esx100-1888888P (fortunately this was only a test database). That solved the problem. I think it happened because I restored a backup of database esx100-1246890P as database esx100-1888888P. I did that to do some testing. Somehow this restore cause this weird issue. It looks like this is something MS has not addressed properly, when a database is restored as another database and when it concerns system-versioned tables.

Comment: Maybe share the script you used to do the `RESTORE`?

Comment: I restored the database using the SSMS database restore. I just changed the database- and filenames. I have done this many times, but never with system versioned tables. It looks to me like MS has not properly addressed this restore. Somehow it messes up the database - table links for history tables.

Comment: The issue isn't going to be in the database itself. The relevant system tables wouldn't even support cross database references. It is just in SSMS. Presumably whatever data structures it use to cache this data can have a bug if same named objects (and object ids) in different databases